# 'npm install' - AngularJS2 (TypeScript) - returning errors

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, npm-install

I'm new to AngularJS - 2 and I'm trying to create my first Angular Application using the following reference https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

I'm using NODE version v6.4.0 and NPM version 3.10.3

Given below is the error :

```
C:\angular-quickstart>npm install
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR!
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Jose and I both found the same npm issue by googling your error message. If you don't understand what's going on, try googling an error message like 'npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN' and seeing which other people had this problem :) Happy coding...

Comment: Sure, I'll... :-)

Comment: npm install --save angular2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Angular-Cli  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

It will solve most of your headache when you facing some task to config webpack or dependency.

Answer (score 3):

According to this issue in the npm repo: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7348

> This appears to be an issue with your internet connection making a DNS lookup.

and:

> EAGAIN is a transient name service failure, so keep retrying your request and it should eventually make it through.

A full explanation of the meaning of `EAI_AGAIN` and where it comes from can be found at: http://www.codingdefined.com/2015/06/nodejs-error-errno-eaiagain.html

Comment: Thank You for telling me the exact cause of the error... :-)